# T24 Telnet Connection on TCP Port Using Python

Tags: python, jboss, tcserver

How can we interact with temenos t24 TCServer on TCP port using Python libraries like `telnet` or `socket`? Has anyone worked on this area?

Answer (score 0):

Easy to connect with Java. Temenos gives standard java libraries to all clients with examples

Comment: Could you add more details to your question and maybe some example code? that would really increase the quality of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect by telnet and then post "tRun tSS [ofs source]"
where ofs source is an id from OFS.SOURCE T24 application (in older T24 command: "tSS [ofs source]" without "tRun"). It allows you to send OFS messages. With OFS you can do almost everything you want in T24 ;)